# Validation before add to cart in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I need to set maximum quantity of products in cart that it's will be not more than 99.

I have following problem:

In AJAX function WooCommerce core it's contain following:

```
public static function add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();

    $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) );
    $quantity          = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
    $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );

    if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) && 'publish' === $product_status ) {

        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );

        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
        }

        // Return fragments
        self::get_refreshed_fragments();

    } else {

        // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
        $data = array(
            'error'       => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ),
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );
    }
}
```

So, even if I will add hook to *woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation* (what I did) — in this case, as you can see from code, it's will redirect me on product page and show me error there.

Do you have any idea how I can stop redirect and show error on the same page?

Thank you.